# Digest calculation of signature fails on Windows, Java 1.8

Tags: java, windows, signature, digest

**The job to do:**

I have got a signed SOAP request and I have to check if the signature is okay. The timestamp of the SOAP message is not of interest.

**My solution so far:**

I made a child class of org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine where in the method processSecurityHeader the check of TimestampProcessor is taken out of concern:

```
public class SignatureSecurityEngine extends WSSecurityEngine {
...
   public WSHandlerResult processSecurityHeader(Element securityHeader, RequestData requestData) throws org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException {
   ...
      Processor p = cfg.getProcessor(el);
      if (p != null) {
         try {
            results = p.handleToken((Element) node, requestData, wsDocInfo);
         } catch (Exception e){
            if (p instanceof TimestampProcessor) {
               // it's okay if timestamp is too old
            } else {
               throw e;
            }
         }
      }
...
```

In fact it's just a copy of WSSecurityEngine with the try/catch added for timestamp processor.

I older versions of wss4j and xmlsec this worked fine.

After a version upgrade of the components, I got the following strange issue:

The calculation of the signature digest **fails** in org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.validate(...) if:

- The programm runs on Windows (JRE)
- I debug on Windows (JDK)
- I debug on Linux (JDK)

**BUT:**

*If the programm runs on Linux (JRE), everything works fine !*

For **both** (Windows/Linux), the configuration is:

- wss4j 2.1.9
- xmlsec 2.0.8
- Java version: 1.8.0_131 (build 1.8.0_131-b11)

**Observation:**

It seems that there remains a standard value ( 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk= ) for the calculated digest.

Any idea?

---

**Additional facts (2017-06-13):**

After Maartens remark I (re)wrote some of the classes (in fact copy & paste) and added some System.out.println to have "debug information" at runtime. Really an odd old style and ugly thing...
But the result was quite interesting!

1. The stream for MessageDigest was never set. So this explains the *2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=* which is the digest for an empty string with SHA-1 (thanks Maarten!)

I managed then to fix - so the stream is now set in my copied "debug"-classes.

**Result:** If I debug now with my IDE, the calculation functions!

***But:*** If I run in runtime the check **fails** :-((( *Reason:* The calculated value is not equal to the expected.

Further observations showed: ev. the wrong calculation depends on the length of the data the digest has to be calculated for (!?!?!?).

Let's have a look at my log:

```
*** Digest for Timestamp
VGDOMReference.validate -> transform:
Expected digest: LxfIdEUVsbyLaevptByfIf2L0PA=
Actual digest: LxfIdEUVsbyLaevptByfIf2L0PA=
Reference[#Timestamp-31b20235-a1e2-4ed0-9658-67611572108e]
*** Digest for Body
Expected digest: Yv+zLpkog+xzAdMlSjoIaZntZLs=
Actual digest: sj2Gb0GEyjWuxoCmnBzDY266aG8=
Reference[#Body-c9761a98-46bb-4175-8f8b-bfa9b5c75509]
```

As you can see the calculation for timestamp is correct. But the one for the body is **wrong**.

Perhaps some stream buffer that is not entirely written?

Comment: exception/stacktrace? Reproducable test case, with configuration?

Comment: Watch out at DOMReference.validate(...): you have this.digestValue {taken from the file} and this.calcDigestValue {newly calculated}. The line this.validationStatus = Arrays.equals(this.digestValue, this.calcDigestValue); results false for validationStatus. It seems to be independent which soap signed file you take, the result for calcDigestValue is always 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=

Comment: You have to make sure that references / namespaces are correct in any scenario that has to do with XML signature verification. I had to explicitly add checks because XML digsig used a path and SOAP the id of an element (or was it the other way around?). If you're getting the same hash value each time the reference may be off. Note that your digest value is **the SHA-1 hash of an empty string**.

Comment: Maybe the last of your worries now, but using SHA-1 for signature generation / verification is of course **not** a good idea anymore.

Comment: SHA-1 is really the last of my worries... - nevertheless: if *check* the signature, you have to take the one which it has been done with!

Answer (score 0):

After some tests it turned out that there was an additional encoding problem... :-(((

The original signed files are in UTF-8, but as Windows uses ISO-xyz_whatever it did not match.

First fix is to put the encoding of JVM in the script that is calling the jar, so:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 <programm>.jar
```

Comment: A better fix would be to specify the encoding when you are converting the bytes from the file into characters. Without having the whole code I don't know where you are going wrong, but this typically happens in an InputStreamReader.

Comment: If this fixed the problem, then you should fix your application by explicitly specifying the encoding where you read the file, not a stopgap measure of overriding the default file encoding.

Comment: Being aware of encoding problems, we adapted the file reading more than 10 years ago... . The point is that with updating the third party components the error came up. wss4j from 1.5.8 to 2.1.9; xmlsec as new dependency. There must be some very hidden bug there. On the other hand if I run webservice projects on the Windows machine that use actually the same classes, there is no problem... (!?!?!?)